# how to start activity by click any where on row

Tags: android

i create Ui same as this picture :

[image]

and below is my xml source cod just tell me how do i set on click listener?so user click anywhere on picture column or anywhere on picture column or video column is start another activity?

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/main_background"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <include
    android:id="@id/includeTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/private_space_title" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/mail_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/main_list_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="20.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="20.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="15.0dip" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@id/picture_part"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="10.0dip" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@id/left_icon1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10.0dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_picture" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/function_img_management"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@id/right_icon1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/listview_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/list_view_divider" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@id/video_part"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="10.0dip" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@id/left_icon2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10.0dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_video" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/function_video_management"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@id/right_icon2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/listview_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/list_view_divider" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@id/sms_call_part"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="10.0dip" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@id/left_icon2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10.0dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_sms_call" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@id/unread_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/left_icon2"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3.0dip"
                        android:background="@drawable/counter"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/function_sms_management"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@id/right_icon3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/listview_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/list_view_divider" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@id/private_contact_part"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="10.0dip" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@id/left_icon4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10.0dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_contact" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/function_privacy_management"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@id/right_icon4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/listview_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/list_view_divider" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@id/break_in_part"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingRight="10.0dip" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@id/left_icon5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10.0dip"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_break_in" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@id/login_record_main_unread_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@id/left_icon5"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3.0dip"
                        android:background="@drawable/counter"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="@string/function_break_in_management"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@id/right_icon5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/listview_arrow" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/list_view_divider" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90.0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@id/member_up_btn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20.0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="20.0dip"
                android:background="@drawable/upgrade_selector"
                android:text="@string/main_upgrade_button"
                android:textSize="18.0sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

just bind a click event for each linearLayout container : picture_part, video_part, sms_call_part...

for example :

```
    LinearLayout menu_photos = (LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.picture_part);
    menu_photos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent picture_intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,PictureActivity.class);
startActivity(picture_intent );     
        }
    });
```

**use the same method for other items.**

Comment: menu_photos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {        isline hsow error

Answer (score 1):

you can set the `onClick` property for each view that you want to click on with a corresponding method.
for example:

```
android:onClick="viewOnClickMethod"
```

and in your `Activity` class define the method:

```
public void viewOnClickMethod (View v)
{
    //from here start any activity you want
}
```

for view that are not designed to be clickable you will have to set the:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

property as well.

Answer (score -1):

You should have used listView and [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29).

This way you could have avoided writing so much XML and also avoid the need to set a listener for each of the rows.

In the listener, check which item was selected and start the activity you wish, by using [startActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)(). if the activity belongs to your app, put its info in the manifest file.

Also, you could have used the action bar instead of the customized upper bar.