# how to set onClick method with linearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am creating an application and posted a question yesterday
[how to start activity by click any where on row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591147/how-to-start-activity-by-click-any-where-on-row).
Got an idea to do like below but I am getting this **error:**

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

Here is my **code:**

```
LinearLayout menu_photos = (LinearLayout )findViewById(R.id.picture_part);
menu_photos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {      
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent picture_intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,PictureActivity.class);
        startActivity(picture_intent );     
    }
});
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/main_background"
   android:orientation="vertical" >
   <include
        android:id="@id/includeTop"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        layout="@layout/private_space_title" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@id/mail_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_list_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10.0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="20.0dip"
    android:paddingRight="20.0dip"
    android:paddingTop="15.0dip" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/picture_part"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="10.0dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/left_icon1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10.0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_picture" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/function_img_management"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/right_icon1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/listview_arrow" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/list_view_divider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/video_part"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="10.0dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/left_icon2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10.0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_video" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/function_video_management"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/right_icon2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/listview_arrow" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/list_view_divider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/sms_call_part"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="10.0dip" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/left_icon2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10.0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_sms_call" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/unread_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/left_icon2"
                android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="3.0dip"
                android:background="@drawable/counter"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/function_sms_management"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/right_icon3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/listview_arrow" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/list_view_divider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/private_contact_part"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="10.0dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/left_icon4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10.0dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_contact" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/function_privacy_management"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/right_icon4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/listview_arrow" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/list_view_divider" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@id/break_in_part"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selector"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="10.0dip" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@id/left_icon5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10.0dip"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_break_in" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@id/login_record_main_unread_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/left_icon5"
                android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="3.0dip"
                android:background="@drawable/counter"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/function_break_in_management"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@id/right_icon5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/listview_arrow" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/list_view_divider" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90.0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <Button
        android:id="@id/member_up_btn"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20.0dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20.0dip"
        android:background="@drawable/upgrade_selector"
        android:text="@string/main_upgrade_button"
        android:textSize="18.0sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

below line is ur code:-

```
menu_photos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

replace this line to below code:-

```
menu_photos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Answer (score 48):

```
LinearLayout app_layer = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.main_activity_app_layer);
app_layer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

set LinearLayout attribute `android:clickable="true"`
if you have any button or textview in layout `set android:clickable="false"` for all of them

Comment: This is the correct answer. android:clickable="booleanValue" is especially useful when dealing with nested layouts and/or to have more control regarding which view is clickable or not.

Answer (score 0):

From your xml layout file i think what you are looking for is a listview, not loads of linearlayouts. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) is nice tutorial to get you started, might be exactly what you need, row with image and text. For the listview just use [setOnItemCLickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29).

Back to what you want, I think you need to make the linearlayout focusable/touchable in order to "receive" clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Great catch by @duggu.
Apart from the answer, using ImageView and TextView inside a LinearLayout, nesting LinearLayout is a bad idea. Instead use `drawableLeft:@src` of a TextView and also for a divider you can use a simple View instead of inflating a drawable.

```
<View
android:background="#aeaeae"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0.5dp"/>
```