# Toggle Checkbox by clicking row layout

Tags: android, checkbox, focus

I have a custom LinearLayout view that has just a TextView and a CheckBox in it.  I can't seem to allow the checkbox to be toggled when any part of the layout is selected.  I've searched around and most of what I see is setting the focusable attributes on the CheckBox to false which I've already done.

I have a similar component with two text views, and the onClick works.

Layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/probe_item_label"
        style="@style/Probe.Item.Text.Label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/probe_item_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Class:

```
public class ProbeItemCheckBox extends LinearLayout
{
   LinearLayout mLayout = null;
   TextView mLabelTextView = null;
   CheckBox mCheckbox = null;

   Context mContext = null;

   public ProbeItemCheckBox(Context context)
   {
      super(context);
   }
   public ProbeItemCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
   {
      super(context, attrs);

      mContext = context;

      TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ProbeText);

      final String labelText = a.getString(R.styleable.ProbeText_labelText);

      String service = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
      LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(service);

      mLayout = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.probe_item_checkbox, this, true);

    //  layout.setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);

      mLabelTextView = (TextView)mLayout.findViewById(R.id.probe_item_label);
      mCheckbox = (CheckBox)mLayout.findViewById(R.id.probe_item_checkbox);

      mCheckbox.setFocusable(false);
      mCheckbox.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

      mLabelTextView.setText(labelText);
      mLabelTextView.setClickable(false);

      mCheckbox.setClickable(false);
      mLayout.setClickable(true);

      mLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
      {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v)
         {
            mCheckbox.toggle();   

         }

      });
      a.recycle();
   }
...
}
```

Any help you could offer would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by toggle?

Comment: @Chitrang Toggle meaning if the checkbox in that row is unchecked, clicking anywhere in the row will check the box, same goes for unchecking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.  I had to find the top level LinearLayout int the xml file by ID and set the onClickListener on that object.

Added ID in layout file:

```
LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/probe_item_checkbox_item_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_settings"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    style="@style/Probe.Item.Layout" >
```

and then find by ID in the java file:

```
  mLayout = (LinearLayout) li.inflate(R.layout.probe_item_checkbox, this, true);

  mLayout2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.probe_item_checkbox_item_layout);
```

Set on click listener on mLayout2

Answer (score 0):

Probably change new OnClickListener() to new View.OnClickListener() in setOnClickListener.

Reference: [how to set onClick method with linearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596507/how-to-set-onclick-method-with-linearlayout)

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work.  It was already using the OnClickListener for the View class, but just for kicks I added it and it did not help.