# Tab the screen twice

Tags: android

app has a type writer effect . A text coming letter by letter. When letters came 3 button appears. I want when user tab the screen 2 times text and buttons should appear. I guess i should use onTouchLister but i can't fix it. Can u help? Thanks for advices.

i have checked this link and tried something: [how to set onClick method with linearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596507/how-to-set-onclick-method-with-linearlayout)

Here is the codes:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);





    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    b.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    invisibleButton(b);

    Button p = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    p.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    invisibleButton(p);

    Button q = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    q.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    invisibleButton(q);






    final TypeWriter tw = (TypeWriter) findViewById(R.id.tv);

    tw.setText("");
    tw.SetCharacterDelay(40);
    tw.animatedText("Ameliyathaneden çıkan doktor, dördüncü kattaki ofisine inmek için asansöre bindi. Yanında bir de hasta vardı. Asansör sekizinci kata gelip durdu ve kapıları açıldı. Asansör kapısının önünde küçük bir çocuk dikiliyordu.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\"Aşağı mı iniyor?\" diye sordu çocuk. Doktor, çocuğu dikkatlice süzdü ve cevap verdi:\n" +
            "\n" +
            "-\"Hayır, yukarı çıkıyor.\" Düğmeye bastı ve asansörün kapıları kapandı. Yanındaki hasta, doktora dönüp sordu:\n" +
            "\n" +
            "-\"Neden çocuğun bizimle birlikte asansöre binmesine izin vermedin? Aşağı iniyorduk zaten.\" Doktor:\n" +
            "\n" +
            "-\"Çocuk çoktan ölmüştü. Geçtiğimiz gün lösemi yüzünden hayatını kaybetti");





    Button btn5 = (Button)   findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent c = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Main3Activity.class);
            startActivity(c);
        }
    });

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view ) {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

}

private void invisibleButton(final View view){

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }, 1000 * 29);

}

    public void onBackPressed(){

    }







}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tried this code but hopfully it will help and guide you:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity{

private long lastClickMillis;
private View lastViewClicked;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    int countButton = 0;
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(lastClickMillis < System.currentMillis()-500 && lastViewClicked.getId() == v.getId())
                // Do whatever you want int the second tab
            }
            lastViewClicked = v;
            lastClickMillis = System.currentMillis()
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: lastViewClicked.getId() == view.getId()) givin this: Non-static method 'getId()' cannot be referenced from a static context   ---                                         lastViewClicked = View; givin this: Expression expected